# How to check the execution time and amount of data for each line of code in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, split, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to optimally split Python code on FaaS to improve response time.

To split the code at the optimal location, I need the execution time of each line and the size of the data on which each line depends.
Is there an appropriate way to obtain these two?

The environment I am using is,

- Azure Functions
- Vscode
- Python programming model v2

By the way, it may not be necessary to split them, but I am going to try to split the activity function in the code below into multiple functions.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing  # Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso  
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error  # MSE(Mean Squared Error)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
### client function ###
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("origin_analysis", '')
    return "finished"


### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/test.txt", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def origin_analysis(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    # prepare data
    california_housing = fetch_california_housing()

    exp_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.data, columns=california_housing.feature_names)
    tar_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.target, columns=['HousingPrices'])
    data = pd.concat([exp_data, tar_data], axis=1)

    # Delete anomalous values
    data = data[data['HouseAge'] != 52]
    data = data[data['HousingPrices'] != 5.00001]

    # Create useful variables
    data['Household'] = data['Population']/data['AveOccup']
    data['AllRooms'] = data['AveRooms']*data['Household']
    data['AllBedrms'] = data['AveBedrms']*data['Household']


    ### simple regression analysis ###
    exp_var = 'MedInc'
    tar_var = 'HousingPrices'

    # Remove outliers
    q_95 = data['MedInc'].quantile(0.95)

    data = data[data['MedInc'] < q_95]

    data = data[data['MedInc'] < q_95]

    # Split data into explanatory and objective variables
    X = data[[exp_var]]
    y = data[[tar_var]]

    # learn
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X, y)

    ### multiple regression analysis ###
    exp_vars = ['MedInc', 'HouseAge', 'AveRooms', 'AveBedrms', 'Population', 'AveOccup', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
    tar_var = 'HousingPrices'

    # Remove outliers
    for exp_var in exp_vars:
        q_95 = data[exp_var].quantile(0.95)
        data = data[data[exp_var] < q_95]

    # Split data into explanatory and objective variables
    X = data[exp_vars]
    y = data[[tar_var]]

    # Split into training and test data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    #  Standardize X_train
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_train_scaled, columns = exp_vars)

    # learn
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

    # Calculate predicted values
    y_pred = model.predict(X_train_scaled)
    y_pred[:10]

    # MSE for test data
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test) # Test data standardized by mean and standard deviation obtained from training data
    y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test_scaled) # Predicting against test data
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)

    # Ridge regression
    ridge = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
    ridge.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    ridge_y_pred = ridge.predict(X_train_scaled)

    # Checking Partial Regression Coefficients
    ridge_w = pd.DataFrame(ridge.coef_.T, index=exp_vars, columns=['Ridge'])
    for xi, wi in zip(exp_vars, ridge.coef_[0]):
        print('{0:7s}: {1:6.3f}'.format(xi, wi))
    
    # Mean Squared Error (MSE) for training data
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred)

    # Mean Squared Error (MSE) for training data
    ridge_mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, ridge_y_pred)

    # MSE for test data
    ridge_y_test_pred = ridge.predict(X_test_scaled) # Predicting against test data
    ridge_mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, ridge_y_test_pred)

    # Lasso regression
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=1.0)
    lasso.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    lasso_y_pred = lasso.predict(X_train_scaled)

    # Checking Partial Regression Coefficients
    lasso_w = pd.Series(index=exp_vars, data=lasso.coef_)

    lasso_mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, lasso_y_pred)

    lasso_X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
    lasso_y_pred_test = lasso.predict(lasso_X_test_scaled)
    lasso_mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, lasso_y_pred_test)

    # Comparison of the accuracy of multiple regression analysis with and without regularization
    data = {'Training data MSE':[mse_train, ridge_mse_train, lasso_mse_train],
            'Test Data MSE':[mse_test, ridge_mse_test, lasso_mse_test],
            'coefficient of determination':[model.score(X_test_scaled, y_test), ridge.score(X_test_scaled, y_test), lasso.score(X_test_scaled, y_test)]}
    df_mse = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['multiple regression', 'Ridge regression', 'Lasso regression'])

    return str(df_mse)
```

Comment: For the execution time, I suggest that you could use Jupyter-notebook and create a separate cell for each line of code.

Comment: Is it impossible for Google colab to recognize execution time in ms?

Comment: pretty much a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74049834/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use time module to check the execution time of the code blocks in your code, I have imported time module and made changes to your code like below:-

**My function_app.py**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing  # Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso  
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error  # MSE(Mean Squared Error)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
import sys
import cProfile
import time

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
### client function ###

@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
   
### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("origin_analysis", '')
    return "finished"


### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/test.txt", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def origin_analysis(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    start_time = time.time()
    # prepare data
    california_housing = fetch_california_housing()

    exp_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.data, columns=california_housing.feature_names)
    tar_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.target, columns=['HousingPrices'])
    data = pd.concat([exp_data, tar_data], axis=1)

    # Delete anomalous values
    data = data[data['HouseAge'] != 52]
    data = data[data['HousingPrices'] != 5.00001]

    # Create useful variables
    data['Household'] = data['Population']/data['AveOccup']
    data['AllRooms'] = data['AveRooms']*data['Household']
    data['AllBedrms'] = data['AveBedrms']*data['Household']


    ### simple regression analysis ###
    exp_var = 'MedInc'
    tar_var = 'HousingPrices'

    # Remove outliers
    q_95 = data['MedInc'].quantile(0.95)

    data = data[data['MedInc'] < q_95]

    data = data[data['MedInc'] < q_95]

    # Split data into explanatory and objective variables
    X = data[[exp_var]]
    y = data[[tar_var]]

    # learn
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X, y)

    ### multiple regression analysis ###
    exp_vars = ['MedInc', 'HouseAge', 'AveRooms', 'AveBedrms', 'Population', 'AveOccup', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
    tar_var = 'HousingPrices'

    # Remove outliers
    for exp_var in exp_vars:
        q_95 = data[exp_var].quantile(0.95)
        data = data[data[exp_var] < q_95]

    # Split data into explanatory and objective variables
    X = data[exp_vars]
    y = data[[tar_var]]

    # Split into training and test data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    #  Standardize X_train
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_train_scaled, columns = exp_vars)

    # learn
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

    # Calculate predicted values
    y_pred = model.predict(X_train_scaled)
    y_pred[:10]

    # MSE for test data
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test) # Test data standardized by mean and standard deviation obtained from training data
    y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test_scaled) # Predicting against test data
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)

    # Ridge regression
    ridge = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
    ridge.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    ridge_y_pred = ridge.predict(X_train_scaled)

    # Checking Partial Regression Coefficients
    ridge_w = pd.DataFrame(ridge.coef_.T, index=exp_vars, columns=['Ridge'])
    for xi, wi in zip(exp_vars, ridge.coef_[0]):
        print('{0:7s}: {1:6.3f}'.format(xi, wi))
    
    # Mean Squared Error (MSE) for training data
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred)

    # Mean Squared Error (MSE) for training data
    ridge_mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, ridge_y_pred)

    # MSE for test data
    ridge_y_test_pred = ridge.predict(X_test_scaled) # Predicting against test data
    ridge_mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, ridge_y_test_pred)

    # Lasso regression
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=1.0)
    lasso.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    lasso_y_pred = lasso.predict(X_train_scaled)

    # Checking Partial Regression Coefficients
    lasso_w = pd.Series(index=exp_vars, data=lasso.coef_)

    lasso_mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, lasso_y_pred)

    lasso_X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
    lasso_y_pred_test = lasso.predict(lasso_X_test_scaled)
    lasso_mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, lasso_y_pred_test)

    # Comparison of the accuracy of multiple regression analysis with and without regularization
    data = {'Training data MSE':[mse_train, ridge_mse_train, lasso_mse_train],
            'Test Data MSE':[mse_test, ridge_mse_test, lasso_mse_test],
            'coefficient of determination':[model.score(X_test_scaled, y_test), ridge.score(X_test_scaled, y_test), lasso.score(X_test_scaled, y_test)]}
    df_mse = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['multiple regression', 'Ridge regression', 'Lasso regression'])
    
    end_time = time.time()
    execution_time = end_time - start_time
    # Measure the size of 'data' here
    data_size = sys.getsizeof(data)
    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds")
    print(f"Size of 'data': {data_size} bytes")
    return str(df_mse)
    # test = cProfile.run(origin_analysis)
    # print(test)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

You can also make use of **cProfile** to get the execution time of each code block, Here's the **`function_app.py`**  code utilizing **cProfile**:-

**function_app.py:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing  # Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso  
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error  # MSE(Mean Squared Error)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
import sys
import cProfile
import time

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
### client function ###

@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
   
### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("origin_analysis", '')
    return "finished"


### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/test.txt", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def origin_analysis(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    start_time = time.time()
    # prepare data
    california_housing = fetch_california_housing()


    exp_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.data, columns=california_housing.feature_names)
    tar_data = pd.DataFrame(california_housing.target, columns=['HousingPrices'])
    data = pd.concat([exp_data, tar_data], axis=1)

    # Delete anomalous values
    data = data[data['HouseAge'] != 52]
    data = data[data['HousingPrices'] != 5.00001]

    # Create useful variables
    data['Household'] = data['Population']/data['AveOccup']
    data['AllRooms'] = data['AveRooms']*data['Household']
    data['AllBedrms'] = data['AveBedrms']*data['Household']


    ### simple regression analysis ###
    exp_var = 'MedInc'
    tar_var = 'HousingPrices'

    # Remove outliers
    q_95 = data['MedInc'].quantile(0.95)

    data = data[data['MedInc'] < q_95]

    data = data[data['MedInc'] < q_95]

    # Split data into explanatory and objective variables
    X = data[[exp_var]]
    y = data[[tar_var]]

    # learn
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X, y)

    ### multiple regression analysis ###
    exp_vars = ['MedInc', 'HouseAge', 'AveRooms', 'AveBedrms', 'Population', 'AveOccup', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
    tar_var = 'HousingPrices'

    # Remove outliers
    for exp_var in exp_vars:
        q_95 = data[exp_var].quantile(0.95)
        data = data[data[exp_var] < q_95]

    # Split data into explanatory and objective variables
    X = data[exp_vars]
    y = data[[tar_var]]

    # Split into training and test data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    #  Standardize X_train
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_train_scaled, columns = exp_vars)

    # learn
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

    # Calculate predicted values
    y_pred = model.predict(X_train_scaled)
    y_pred[:10]

    # MSE for test data
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test) # Test data standardized by mean and standard deviation obtained from training data
    y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test_scaled) # Predicting against test data
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)

    # Ridge regression
    ridge = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
    ridge.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    ridge_y_pred = ridge.predict(X_train_scaled)

    # Checking Partial Regression Coefficients
    ridge_w = pd.DataFrame(ridge.coef_.T, index=exp_vars, columns=['Ridge'])
    for xi, wi in zip(exp_vars, ridge.coef_[0]):
        print('{0:7s}: {1:6.3f}'.format(xi, wi))
    
    # Mean Squared Error (MSE) for training data
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred)

    # Mean Squared Error (MSE) for training data
    ridge_mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, ridge_y_pred)

    # MSE for test data
    ridge_y_test_pred = ridge.predict(X_test_scaled) # Predicting against test data
    ridge_mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, ridge_y_test_pred)

    # Lasso regression
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=1.0)
    lasso.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    lasso_y_pred = lasso.predict(X_train_scaled)

    # Checking Partial Regression Coefficients
    lasso_w = pd.Series(index=exp_vars, data=lasso.coef_)

    lasso_mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train, lasso_y_pred)

    lasso_X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
    lasso_y_pred_test = lasso.predict(lasso_X_test_scaled)
    lasso_mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, lasso_y_pred_test)
    profiler = cProfile.Profile()
    profiler.enable()

    # Comparison of the accuracy of multiple regression analysis with and without regularization
    data = {'Training data MSE':[mse_train, ridge_mse_train, lasso_mse_train],
            'Test Data MSE':[mse_test, ridge_mse_test, lasso_mse_test],
            'coefficient of determination':[model.score(X_test_scaled, y_test), ridge.score(X_test_scaled, y_test), lasso.score(X_test_scaled, y_test)]}
    df_mse = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['multiple regression', 'Ridge regression', 'Lasso regression'])
    profiler.disable()
    profiler.print_stats(sort='cumtime')
    end_time = time.time()
    execution_time = end_time - start_time
    # Measure the size of 'data' here
    data_size = sys.getsizeof(data)
    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds")
    print(f"Size of 'data': {data_size} bytes")
    return str(df_mse)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]